# How to pass a shared_ptr using win32 API PostMessage() to another thread?

Tags: shared-ptr

Win32 API:[PostMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
BOOL WINAPI PostMessage(
  _In_opt_ HWND   hWnd,
  _In_     UINT   Msg,
  _In_     WPARAM wParam,
  _In_     LPARAM lParam
);
```

I have a `shared_ptr` created in a worker thread, and I need to pass it to the UI thread. How can I do it?

I have defined my own message `WM_USER_THREAD`, `hWnd` is the main window.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2515285/2864740 - note LPARAM's definition. (Concurrency / access issues are a separate animal.)

Comment: @user2864740, thanks for your link. But LPARAM is a raw pointer. How to hold a shared_ptr?

Comment: How would one pass any object as a pointer? [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is just a class of which instances are created.. Imagine this: what if the 'passed' object was: `struct { shared_ptr<..> my_ptr; }`? It's the same for a shared_ptr object, just with one less level of indirection.

Comment: This question has in-depth analysis and may help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667226/how-can-i-use-shared-ptr-using-postthreadmessage